# Get Response Date with get_responses

Tags: surveymonkey

We know we can query for responses between dates using get_respondent_list, however, how can we retrieve the actual response date that corresponds to when the survey was taken? Is this exposed through the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) you can request the `date_start` and `date_modified` fields.  These contain when the survey response was started and when it was last modified by the user, i.e. when they finished the survey or last updated it.  You can't get any more detailed information than that (e.g. a full list of dates that the survey response was updated by the user).

Comment: Got it. You must pass the fields you want returned (e.g. date_start) in the JSON results using the 'fields' parameter in get_respondent_list. That was not initially clear.